# Jackson 2.6.0 JsonParser#getCurrentValue() returns null instead of value of JSON property

Tags: java, jackson, jsonparser, jackson2, jsonnode

In Jackson 2.6.0, `JsonParser#getCurrentValue()` returns `null` instead of the value of the currently parsed JSON property.

The example method at the end of this question prints:

```bash
a
null
```

But I expect it to print:

```bash
a
b
```

Why is `null` printed instead of `b`?

How can I get the value of the current JSON property as an `Object`, so that it will return a `String`, `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, `Float`, `BigDecimal`, etc., or `null`, as appropriate?

I know that there'd have to be an algorithm that determines when to return, e.g., `1` as an `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, `BigDecimal`, or some other `Number` subclass, but I imagine that there'd be a default algorithm that could be replaced by a custom algorithm.

Example method:

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser("{\"a\":\"b\"}");

    while (jsonParser.nextValue() != null) {
        final Object value = jsonParser.getCurrentValue();
        final String name  = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
        if (name != null) {
            System.out.println(name + "\n" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of different things at work here.

First: `getCurrentValue()` is NOT maintained by low-level streaming API itself at all, so your code would never see a non-null value. Instead, it is managed by databinding (higher level), based on Java POJO Objects, which are only handled at databinding.
The reason methods themselves are in `JsonParser` and `JsonGenerator` is due to practical limitations, as parser/generator are passed through processing, are available to `JsonSerializer` / `JsonDeserializer`, and have hierarchic scope: conceptually this information would belong at databinding level completely.

If you want to only operate on streaming level, these methods will not be of use to you. You need to keep track of all the information yourself.
Alternatively, perhaps you should bind JSON as `JsonNode` using `ObjectMapper`, and then traverse the logical in-memory tree. Streaming processing minimizes amount of state it keeps, which is not necessarily very convenient for most operations.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I assume that I'll just make a helper method that has `JsonToken t = jsonParser.nextValue(); switch (t) {...}`, and, based on the value of `t`, calls the correct `jsonParser.get*()` method.  I assume that, it it's `VALUE_NUMBER_INT or `VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT``, I'll have it figure out the smallest sublclass of `Number` that will hold the whole value, and return that, or just always use BigInteger and BigDecimal.

Comment: If you don't add a similar switch implementation in `getCurrentValue()`, it might make sense to mention in the JavaDoc that this method will always return null if you're using a plain `JsonParser`, and that the user should use a switch on the current `JsonToken` to get the current value of any type.

Comment: @XDR agreed, javadocs should be improved -- I understand why you could easily assume it is available and useful at that level

Comment: One other thing: for VALUE_NUMBER_INT and VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT you can use `getNumberValue()`, it will indeed return "smallest" applicable type for `VALUE_NUMBER_INT`; otherwise either `Double` or `BigDecimal` (depending on configuration)